# Print Arabic Or Persion Character From Android Device Via Bluetooth Printer (Bixolon SPP-R300)

Tags: printing

I want to print arabic or persian character via bluetooth printer.I use unicode "utf-8" but printer print a lot of charactor. Is there any simple project to print that?
Thanks for your help.